Rotation of sceneView.pointOfView Around the Axis of the root node
How can we ensure that the rotation of sceneView.pointOfView occurs around the axis of the root node?
Code:
import SceneKit

var myScene = SCNScene()

class RootVC: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    
    lazy var sceneView: SCNView = {
        let view = SCNView()
        return view
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.setupSceneView()
        
        let cameraNode = SCNNode()
        cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
        cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(0.0, 0.0, +10.0)
        myScene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)
        
        self.setupiPad()
        
        setupGesture()
    
    }
    
    func setupGesture() {
        let doubleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(doubleTapped))
        doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
        doubleTap.delegate = self
        sceneView.addGestureRecognizer(doubleTap)
    }
    
    @objc func doubleTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        SCNTransaction.begin()
        SCNTransaction.animationDuration = 1
        
        sceneView.pointOfView?.transform = SCNMatrix4(m11: -0.99805325, m12: 9.313226e-10, m13: -0.062367648, m14: 0.0, m21: 0.001364812, m22: 0.9997605, m23: -0.021840723, m24: 0.0, m31: 0.062352777, m32: -0.021883326, m33: -0.9978142, m34: 0.0, m41: 0.61549366, m42: -0.21884802, m43: -9.97974, m44: 1.0)
        sceneView.pointOfView?.camera?.fieldOfView = 60
        
        SCNTransaction.commit()
    }
    
    func setupiPad() {
        let iPadNode = SCNNode(named: "Apple_iPad_Pro.usdz")
        // iPadNode.pivot = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(0.0, +150.0, 0.0)
        iPadNode.scale = SCNVector3(0.01, 0.01, 0.01)
        iPadNode.setPivotCenter()
        myScene.rootNode.addChildNode(iPadNode)
    }
    
    func setupSceneView() {
        
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        
        // MARK: Setup SceneView
        // sceneView.delegate                              = self
        view.addSubview(sceneView)
        
        sceneView.frame                                 = view.frame
        sceneView.isPlaying                             = true
        sceneView.backgroundColor                       = .black
        sceneView.antialiasingMode                      = .none
        sceneView.isJitteringEnabled                    = false
        sceneView.autoenablesDefaultLighting            = true
        sceneView.allowsCameraControl                   = false
        //sceneView.rendersContinuously                   = true
        
        // MARK: Set Scene and Configs
        sceneView.scene                                 = myScene
        sceneView.scene?.rootNode.castsShadow           = false
        
        // MARK: Scene Physics Configuration
        // sceneView.scene?.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
        // sceneView.scene?.physicsWorld.gravity           = defaultGravity
        // sceneView.scene?.physicsWorld.timeStep       = 1/240 // 1/120 // DO NOT SET
        // sceneView.scene?.physicsWorld.speed          = 1.0 // not configured
        
        // MARK: Environment
        myScene.lightingEnvironment.contents          = UIColor.white
        myScene.background.contents                   = UIColor.white
        
        // MARK: Debug Options (Disabled)
        // sceneView.showsStatistics                    = true // statistics such as fps and timing information
        // sceneView.debugOptions                       = [SCNDebugOptions.showPhysicsShapes]
        // sceneView.debugOptions                       = [SCNDebugOptions.showBoundingBoxes]
        // sceneView.debugOptions                       = [SCNDebugOptions.showSkeletons]
        // sceneView.debugOptions                       = [SCNDebugOptions.showWireframe]
        // sceneView.debugOptions                       = [SCNDebugOptions.renderAsWireframe]
        // sceneView.debugOptions                       = [SCNDebugOptions.showLightExtents, SCNDebugOptions.showLightInfluences]
        
        print("SceneView and Scene setup completed")
    }

    
}

extension SCNNode {
    func setPivotCenter() {
        let (min, max) = boundingBox
        let x = min.x + 0.5 * (max.x - min.x)
        let y = min.y + 0.5 * (max.y - min.y)
        let z = min.z + 0.5 * (max.z - min.z)
        self.pivot = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(x, y, z)
    }
}

extension SCNNode {
    convenience init(named name: String) {
        self.init()
        guard let scene = SCNScene(named: name) else {return}
        for childNode in scene.rootNode.childNodes {addChildNode(childNode)}
    }
}


Note: I don't want to apply rotation directly to the root or any other nodes.
Incorrect results:

What I need:

3d object image:


You did: scene.rootNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 282.523/2, z: 0) - according to Apples Documentation, you must not change the properties of the Scene's Root-Node.

Thank you, but this is unrelated to the current issue. Do you have a solution to the problem?

@ZAY comment might not solve the issue, but it is important to not change position of root node, as it might affect the scene


Dont's change Rood Node Properties. 2. Make sure, the pivot is really in the center of the geometry you add to the scene. You might want to review that in an external Program like Blender. As your object rotates concentric, I assume, it's a Pivot Issue. 3. I'll add an answer how to make the Look at constraint as an example for you.


I updated the question to include the 3D model image (with axis). This code merely adjusts the y-axis position: scene.rootNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 282.523/2, z: 0). I've experimented with other 3D models possessing a centered axis position, and I presume the issue is unrelated to this. Waiting for the proposed solution. Thanks in advanced.

just shifting the pivot:
your node.pivot = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(0.0, +yourObjectHeight / 2, 0.0)

Option #1 (Easier):
Instead of rotating the PointOfView camera, you can get the node reference (-childNodeWithName:recursively:) simply rotate the node on its own axis.
Option #2:
Use SCNLookAtConstraint on the camera and simply move the camera position.

Could you provide an example for option 2? I tried this code: let lookAtConstraint = SCNLookAtConstraint(target: scene.rootNode) sceneView.pointOfView?.constraints = [lookAtConstraint], but it doesn't work.

This is an example, how to setup a look at constraint:
func addConstraint() {
    let lookAtConstraint = SCNLookAtConstraint(target: constrainToNode)
    // lookAtConstraint.targetOffset = SCNVector3(0.0, 2.0, 0.0) // you can add an offset
    // lookAtConstraint.influenceFactor = 1.0 // you can add influence factor
    lookAtConstraint.isGimbalLockEnabled = true // important for cameras
        
    // create and add a camera to the scene
    cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
    cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(0.0, 0.0, 15.0)
    // cameraNode.look(at: SCNVector3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)) // one time look at action - not a constraint
    cameraNode.constraints = [lookAtConstraint] // add the constraint to the array of constraints
    gameScene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)
}

Note: The look at constraint will focus the pivot point of the constrained node.
There is also a position constraint available that works similar to the look at constraint.
let positionConstraint = SCNReplicatorConstraint(target: constrainToNode)
Feel free to share you project, so we can better understand what's going on.
***** UPDATE *****
replace the contents of your root controller with this here. It's a bit quick, but the result seems better now. It might require fine tuning.
import SceneKit

var myScene = SCNScene()

class RootVC: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    
    lazy var sceneView: SCNView = {
        let view = SCNView()
        return view
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.setupSceneView()
        
        let cameraNode = SCNNode()
        cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
        cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(0.0, 0.0, +10.0)
        myScene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)
        
        self.setupiPad()
    }
    
    func setupiPad() {
        let iPadNode = SCNNode(named: "Apple_iPad_Pro.usdz")
        // iPadNode.pivot = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(0.0, +150.0, 0.0)
        iPadNode.scale = SCNVector3(0.01, 0.01, 0.01)
        iPadNode.setPivotCenter()
        myScene.rootNode.addChildNode(iPadNode)
    }
    
    func setupSceneView() {
        
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        
        // MARK: Setup SceneView
        // sceneView.delegate                              = self
        view.addSubview(sceneView)
        
        sceneView.frame                                 = view.frame
        sceneView.isPlaying                             = true
        sceneView.backgroundColor                       = .black
        sceneView.antialiasingMode                      = .none
        sceneView.isJitteringEnabled                    = false
        sceneView.autoenablesDefaultLighting            = true
        sceneView.allowsCameraControl                   = true
        sceneView.rendersContinuously                   = true
        
        // MARK: Set Scene and Configs
        sceneView.scene                                 = myScene
        sceneView.scene?.rootNode.castsShadow           = false
        
        // MARK: Scene Physics Configuration
        // sceneView.scene?.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
        // sceneView.scene?.physicsWorld.gravity           = defaultGravity
        // sceneView.scene?.physicsWorld.timeStep       = 1/240 // 1/120 // DO NOT SET
        // sceneView.scene?.physicsWorld.speed          = 1.0 // not configured
        
        // MARK: Environment
        myScene.lightingEnvironment.contents          = UIColor.white
        myScene.background.contents                   = UIColor.white
        
        // MARK: Debug Options (Disabled)
        // sceneView.showsStatistics                    = true // statistics such as fps and timing information
        // sceneView.debugOptions                       = [SCNDebugOptions.showPhysicsShapes]
        // sceneView.debugOptions                       = [SCNDebugOptions.showBoundingBoxes]
        // sceneView.debugOptions                       = [SCNDebugOptions.showSkeletons]
        // sceneView.debugOptions                       = [SCNDebugOptions.showWireframe]
        // sceneView.debugOptions                       = [SCNDebugOptions.renderAsWireframe]
        // sceneView.debugOptions                       = [SCNDebugOptions.showLightExtents, SCNDebugOptions.showLightInfluences]
        
        print("SceneView and Scene setup completed")
    }
    
}

extension SCNNode {
    func setPivotCenter() {
        let (min, max) = boundingBox
        let x = min.x + 0.5 * (max.x - min.x)
        let y = min.y + 0.5 * (max.y - min.y)
        let z = min.z + 0.5 * (max.z - min.z)
        self.pivot = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(x, y, z)
    }
}

extension SCNNode {
    convenience init(named name: String) {
        self.init()
        guard let scene = SCNScene(named: name) else {return}
        for childNode in scene.rootNode.childNodes {addChildNode(childNode)}
    }
}


when applying sceneView.pointOfView?.runAction(rotationAction) I get same incorrect results. Did I miss something?

why do you do this?
sceneView.pointOfView?.runAction(rotationAction) - using allows camera control = true is already designed to move the camera to the initial PoV. Or do I misunderstand something?

I want to rotate sceneView.pointOfView according to the root axis. Why? Because when I want to move the 3D model from one pointOfView to another, the animation applied via SCNTransaction uses the axis of the pointOfView. So, I need a way to force it to use the 3D model's axis itself.

I think, I don't really understand your needs here... I think my answer does more or less what you mentioned in your question "What I need:..."

Just use your code and perform a rotation around the Y axis, then double-click. You will notice a strange rotation axis. gif: https://jumpshare.com/s/AFXCe3JzyWPXucckCRzo

yeah, this is the behaviour of allowsCameraControl = true - if you want to rotate it back around an axis of the node you look at you will need some manual implementation of the camera rotation scenario. You could i.Ex. add the camera node to the iPad Node, and perform some rotation animation for it. in that case you need to set allowsCameraControl to false.

I have updated my question and integrated your code with some modifications to demonstrate my animation approach based on the point of view. Could you please update your answer to include your solution?

well, the solution, without the help of allowsCameraControl = true depends up on your needs. you will have to implement your very own rotation mechanism to achieve the desired behaviour. There are several solutions online how to rotate a Node (here: the camera Node). Enabling allowsCameraControl changes the entire behaviour, how the camera is driven. when you move the camera, you do in fact not move the camera from the setup, but in internal object created for you by SceneKit. double tapping returns it to the defaults cam's PoV. Hard to tell, what would be the best approach for your needs.
